# how to load nested data from json file in react

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

i have simple json file like this:

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "How to become a best sale marketer in a month!",
        "Summary": "Lorm voluptatem reecto, quos amet hic aliquid!",
        "dateAdd": "May 9, 2021",
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "child": [{
            "base": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "SEO trend to look for the best in 2020",
        "Summary": "Lorem ipsum",
        "dateAdd": "May 9, 2020",
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "child": [{
            "base": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        }]

    }]
```

this is my blog component that uses the json data:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import data from "../../layout/data.json";

const _Blog = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-md-8">
        {data.map((postDetail, index) => {
          return (
            <article className="blog-post-item">
              <div className="post-thumb">
                <img
                  src="assets/images/blog/news-1.jpg"
                  alt=""
                  className="img-fluid"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="post-item mt-4">
                <div className="post-meta">
                  <span className="post-date">
                    <i className="fa fa-calendar-alt mr-2"></i>{postDetail.dateAdd}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <h2 className="post-title">
                  <a href="blog-single.html">
                    {postDetail.title}
                  </a>
                </h2>
                <div className="post-content">
                  <p>
                    {postDetail.body}
                  </p>
                  <h5 key={index}>
                    <Link to={`/blog-detail/${index + 1}`}>More</Link>
                  </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export const Blog = _Blog;
```

it works correctly but i want to use the data from the child object. so i thought i should use it like this:
{postDetail.child.base} but it wont load it. Im totally lost at this point. How does {postDetail.title} or {postDetail.body} work but not the child part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't access `postDetail.child.base` probably because `postDetail.child` is an array.
Try accessing it like `postDetail.child[0].base`.

Hope that helps.. Leave a comment if your issue is different. I'll edit my response

*It should've been a comment but I don't have enough reputation.*